# Foursquare API - cannot edit venue I am a manager of

Tags: api, foursquare

I am using the Foursquare API to add/edit venues. I have created a FS user, and created my app. I have done the oAuth token exchange and have my user token.

From here I can make the required API calls to add a venue, get this venue, and then edit this venue. This works brilliantly, like a charm.

I was then made a manager of a different venue. In the FS web front-end, I am able to view this venue, and manage it - i.e. change it's name and so on.

When I then try and change this second venue via the API I get the following response:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 403,
    "errorType": "not_authorized",
    "errorDetail": "User not authorized to edit venue"
  },
  "response": {}
}
```

The only difference between the API call that works, and the one that doesn't, is the FS Venue ID (which I know is correct). I'm obviously missing something, but I have no idea what - any thoughts?

Comment: are you using the same user token as you generated before you were made manager? what happens if you generate a new user token and try the call again?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion.  I have just tried this, and the generated token was the same as the previous one. It does say in the docs that these tokens never expire (https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth)

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems to be that when you add someone as an owner of the venue via the website, this action only allows this person to manage the Venue via the website. Think of it as the FS website is simply a FS App, like yours or mine.

It might be considered a bit odd if my app could authorise your app to act as manager for one of my users, I suppose.